# sbt 0.13.17 "Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface"

Tags: java, scala, compiler-errors, compilation, sbt

When I execute the 'run' command on the Windows Terminal for a trivial Scala program, this error is raised:

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#interface;0.13.17 ...
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface'
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 15 Jun 2018, 23:36:48
```

I am using `jdk 1.8.0_172`, `scala version 2.11.8,` and `sbt version 0.13.17`. The only library dependency I have is `org.scalatest version 3.0.0`. I have been following a Coursera course on Scala which is why I'm using these specific (I believe dated?) versions.

Comment: Can you share the build.sbt?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Chenthil in the comment to the deleted answer:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4"
```

fixes this.

Comment: @Chenthil: post your own answer and @-reply to me anytime to replace this